# Can't update widget data using Getx controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Data inside widgets do not update.

Following best practice for reusing the code of widgets. I have `DashboardScreen` and `DashboardScreenController`, the code provided below:

**Dashboard Screen:**

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final DashboardController controller = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: controller.scaffoldKey,
      body: _buildProfile(data: controller.getProfil()),
  }

  Widget _buildProfile({required Profile data}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kSpacing),
      child: _ProfilTile(
        data: data,
        onPressedLogOut: () {
          controller.logoutUser();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**Dashboard Controller:**

```
class DashboardController extends GetxController {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  // for handling authenticaion
  final AuthService _authService = Get.find();
  final _localSecureStorage = Get.find<LocalSecureStorage>();

  Rx<User?> currentUser = null.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    assignCurrentUser();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void assignCurrentUser() async {
    User? secureData = await _localSecureStorage.getUser;
    currentUser.update((currentUser) => currentUser = secureData);
  }

  // Data
  Profile getProfil() {
    return Profile(
      photo: const AssetImage(ImageRasterPath.avatar1),
      name: currentUser.value != null
          ? currentUser.value!.username.toString()
          : "Loading..",
      email: currentUser.value != null
          ? currentUser.value!.email.toString()
          : "Loading..",
    );
  }
```

and the reusable piece is the profile widget:

```
class _ProfilTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ProfilTile(
      {required this.data, required this.onPressedLogOut, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final Profile data;
  final Function() onPressedLogOut;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(data.name),
      subtitle: Text(data.email),
    );
  }
}
```

**I've tried:**

1. just use `User? currentUser` instead of using 'Rx<User?> currentUser'
   but this isn't healping to update UI, only works after *hot reload*
2. tried to use `Obx()` widget in all possible ways by

- refactoring `_buildProfile(data: controller.getProfil())` in dashboard
- refactoring `ListTile` widget in _ProfilTile
- refactoring each `Text()` independently  in _ProfilTile
  all gives me an error

> improper use of a GetX has been detected. using bottomNavigationBar

3. Tried to use function `update()` and `refresh()` inside controller in the `assignCurrentUser` function

still have same issue after all. the flow of my app is that I get the user from my secure local storage by using `await` and update user data in controller and updated data in screen by passing it to widget `_ProfileTile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you need to wrap widgets that need to be updated inside an `Obx` widget.

**Dashbord Screen:**

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final DashboardController controller = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: controller.scaffoldKey,
      body: Obx(() => _buildProfile(data: controller.getProfil())),
  }

  ...
}
```

Then inside the `DashboardController` you can update the `currentUser` value this way:

**Dashboard Controller:**

```
class DashboardController extends GetxController {

  final Rx<User?> currentUser = Rx<User?>(null);
  ...

  void assignCurrentUser() async {
    User? secureData = await _localSecureStorage.getUser;
    currentUser.value = secureData;
  }

 ...
}
```

Comment: npw because of this line `Rx<User?> currentUser = null.obs;` when I try to assign vale `currentUser.value = secureData;` it gives me error `Unhandled Exception: type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'Null' of 'val'` any ideas?

Comment: @PoulaAdel I just updated my answer. Check how I assigned the initial value of `currentUser`